# Comparison between big numbers doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, if-statement

The program I wrote takes two numbers and makes a division and a modulo operation.

The code is

```
#define ADDRESS_SPACE 4294967295
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long int pagesize = atoi(argv[1]), virtaddr = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (virtaddr >= ADDRESS_SPACE) {puts("Address is too large"); return 1;}

    printf("%lu\n", virtaddr);
    printf("%lu\n", ADDRESS_SPACE);
    printf("Page = %lu\nOffset = %lu\n", virtaddr/pagesize, virtaddr%pagesize);
    return 0;
}
```

And doing `./page 1024 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` gives the following output

```
18446744073709551615
4294967295
Page = 0
Offset = 18446744073709551615
```

If `virtaddr` is bigger than `ADDRESS_SPACE`, why isn't the if statement working? I know there's an overflow, but printing the variables doesn't show any error and they are still numbers (the maximum value a long int can take).

Comment: Um... maybe it's because `9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` is too big to fit into an `unsigned long`?

Comment: Your variables are signed but you're printing them unsigned.

Comment: (And atoi returns an int.)  (Hint: Compare virtaddr to zero)

Comment: It works with the unsigned specifier. Sorry about the silly question, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`18446744073709551615` is the unsigned version of -1. `virtaddr` is signed but you displayed it as unsigned; of course -1 is going to be less than any valid positive number.

Answer (score 2):

Because `atoi` converts from ASCII to `ints` and not to `long ints` and also `9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` is far to big to be converted into an `int`.

Try using [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) for the string conversion and also try a more reasonable number.

Comment: The number was used to test what would happen in the case of an overflow. But looks like it was just the unsigned bit that was missing. It works now even with the stupidly big number.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` returns `INT_MAX` when the number is out of range. Comparing a 32-bit `int` to `4294967295` is always false, because `INT_MAX` is roughly two times smaller. If you use [`strtoll`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) instead of `atoi`, your solution will work, because the result will be in the range of `long long`. Alternatively, you could use `INT_MAX` instead of `ADDRESS_SPACE`.

Comment: Actually `atoi` invoked undefined behavior on overflow. This function should never be used.

Comment: @R.. Not according to [the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/): "If the correct value is out of the range of representable values, INT_MAX or INT_MIN is returned."

Comment: That site is anything but "the reference". It's the #1 source of misinformation about C and C++ on the net. Don't use it. Read the standard. 7.20.1.2: "The atoi, atol, and atoll functions convert the initial portion of the string pointed to by nptr to int, long int, and long long int representation, respectively. Except for the behavior on error, they are equivalent to...  atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)" The only questionable part is what it means by "except for the behavior on error" and failing to specify any behavior on error...

Comment: ...however in the case of equivalence there, calling `strtol` and casting to `int` would not give the value of `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN` on overflow of `int`. Instead it would give an implementation-defined conversion of `long`. POSIX's version of the spec (which is supposed to be aligned with C) is more explicit: "If the value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined." (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html)